# Submit button which RedirectToAction to previusly page.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I have one method which I use in some place. Now I make RedirectToActio.... and back me to the concrete page. Is possible to make, it back to previusly page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Referer HTTP header but it's not very reliable. A better way is to pass the url you want to redirect to the controller action (it's the way the POST `LogOn` method on the `AccountController` is implemented when you create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the built in wizard. Take a look at it):

```
public ActionResult Foo(string returnUrl)
{
    ...
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Then when you call this action you pass the url of the current page. For example you could generate the following anchor:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "do some processing and redirect back here", 
    "foo", 
    new { returnurl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri }
)
```